# Flex: dynamically add effects based on events

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, effects

Is it possible to add event-based effects to Flex components (showEffect, hideEffect, addedEffect,...)? We can register them in MXML declaration

```
<s:TitleWindow showEffect="{myShowEffect}"/>
```

Can i do the same in AS code (like *setStyle()* for styles)? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the hood, effects are implemented as styles.  So, set an effect in ActionScript the same way you'd set a style:

```
titleWindow.setStyle('showEffect',myShowEffect);
```

The style approach sometimes feels like a kludge for everything not implemented as a real property.